# UIBarButtonItem on UINavigationBar in UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uitabbaritem

I'm new here. Sorry for may English.

I work on an iPhone application, which has an Tab Bar Controller (within an Navigation Controller). The Tab Bar Controller has four tabs and an Navigation Bar with default Back Button. I will set an other Bar Button Item on this Navigation Bar (on Tab Bar Controller). That is easy with drag and drop on storyboard, but I can't set an action for this new bar button item.

I know that I should set up a delegate for my UITabBarController, but I don't know how.
Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You usually create IBOutlets/IBActions by cntrl+dragging outlet from the story board to your code.Try to do the following:
[image]

Don't forget to switch to assistant editor to split your screen

[image]

Click on this button to switch to assistant editor

Comment: I know this, but for an UITabBarController how can I assign a code file?

Comment: please look at this screenshot: http://i45.tinypic.com/5foow9.png I will write event for the button item from the top-right corner.

Comment: that's exactly what I showed on my image..cntrl+click on the nav button and drug to the code (to be able to see both story board and your .h file you need to click on assistnant editor button)